# Antialiasing of Curves by Discrete Pre-filtering

Tags: python, math, graphics

I'm looking to implement the bezier curve algorithm described in the paper ["Antialiasing of Curves by Discrete Pre-filtering" by A.E. Fabris and A.R. Forrest.](http://pdf.aminer.org/000/593/297/antialiasing_of_curves_by_discrete_pre_filtering.pdf) However I'm missing a core piece of the puzzle: the point containment algorithm for curves by Corthout and Pol. It's outlined in the book *Raster Imaging and Digital Typography*.

I could simply iterate over every pixel, calculate the shortest distance to the bezier, and use that to calculate the effect of the brush. However as mentioned in the paper it's an inefficient approach.

Is there an outline or pseudo code for the point containment algorithm (or equivalent) that would do the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer my own question seeing that I've figured it out. Turns out point containment isn't needed, and was already outlined in the paper.

Here's the implementation in python and wxwidgets, rendering a few curves using the box brush.

Sadly it's too slow for practical use, even after rewriting it in C and making several optimisations. The best I could get it was about 30ms per bezier, and rendering a picture of 100 curves took 3 seconds. Most other vector applications tend to use path based bezier rendering algorithms which is what I'll be exploring now.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# test15.py

import wx
import math
import cProfile

class Brush(object):
    def __init__(self, size):
        self._brushsize = size
        self.__halfbrush = self._brushsize / 2
    # returns true if inside or touching box
    def insidebox(self, box):
        minp = box[0]
        maxp = box[1]
        if maxp.x < -self.__halfbrush:
            return False
        if minp.x > self.__halfbrush:
            return False
        if maxp.y < -self.__halfbrush:
            return False
        if minp.y > self.__halfbrush:
            return False
        return True

    def at(self, p):
        px = p.x * p.x # 0.027
        py = p.y * p.y 
        d = math.sqrt(px + py)
        return  d < self.__halfbrush


    def getSize(self):
        return self._brushsize

class BezierPoint(object):
    SCALEFACTOR = 4 # we divide each pixel into 4x4 matrix

    @classmethod
    def newRealPoint(nbs, x,y):
        x=int(x*BezierPoint.SCALEFACTOR)
        y=int(y*BezierPoint.SCALEFACTOR)
        return BezierPoint(x,y)

    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=int(x)
        self.y=int(y)

    def __str__(self):
        return  self.x+ 'x' + self.y

#recalls = 0

class QuadBezier(object): # cubic bezier
    COVERED = 0x01
    NOT_COVERED = 0x02

    @classmethod
    def newRealPoint(nbs, x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4):
        b = QuadBezier(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4)
        b.p1 = BezierPoint.newRealPoint( x1, y1)
        b.p2 = BezierPoint.newRealPoint( x2, y2)
        b.p3 = BezierPoint.newRealPoint( x3, y3)
        b.p4 = BezierPoint.newRealPoint( x4, y4)
        b._minx = min(b.p1.x,b.p2.x,b.p3.x,b.p4.x)
        b._maxx = max(b.p1.x,b.p2.x,b.p3.x,b.p4.x)
        b._miny = min(b.p1.y,b.p2.y,b.p3.y,b.p4.y)
        b._maxy = max(b.p1.y,b.p2.y,b.p3.y,b.p4.y)
        return b

    def __init__(self,x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4):
        self.p1 = BezierPoint(x1,y1)
        self.p2 = BezierPoint(x2,y2)
        self.p3 = BezierPoint(x3,y3)
        self.p4 = BezierPoint(x4,y4)
        self._minx = min(x1,x2,x3,x4)
        self._maxx = max(x1,x2,x3,x4)
        self._miny = min(y1,y2,y3,y4)
        self._maxy = max(y1,y2,y3,y4)

    def __str__(self):
        s = 'p1 = ' + str(self.p1.x) +'x'+ str(self.p1.y) +' p2 = '+str(self.p2.x) +'x'+str(self.p2.y)
        s = s + ' p3 = ' + str(self.p3.x) +'x'+ str(self.p3.y) +' p4 = '+str(self.p4.x) +'x'+str(self.p4.y)
        return  s

    def subdivide(self, left=True):
        # http://antigrain.com/research/adaptive_bezier/
        # according to the paper, we control vertices need to be performed at
        # higher precision than the discrete space will allow to for any accuracy loss 
        x1 = self.p1.x << 2 
        x2 = self.p2.x << 2 
        x3 = self.p3.x << 2
        x4 = self.p4.x << 2
        y1 = self.p1.y << 2
        y2 = self.p2.y << 2
        y3 = self.p3.y << 2
        y4 = self.p4.y << 2
        x12   = (x1 + x2) >> 1
        y12   = (y1 + y2) >> 1
        x23   = (x2 + x3) >> 1
        y23   = (y2 + y3) >> 1
        x34   = (x3 + x4) >> 1
        y34   = (y3 + y4) >> 1
        x123  = (x12 + x23) >> 1
        y123  = (y12 + y23) >> 1
        x234  = (x23 + x34) >> 1
        y234  = (y23 + y34) >> 1
        x1234 = (x123 + x234) >> 1
        y1234 = (y123 + y234) >> 1

        if left:
            return QuadBezier(x1 >> 2, y1 >> 2, x12 >> 2, y12 >> 2, x123 >> 2, y123 >> 2, x1234 >> 2, y1234 >> 2)
        return QuadBezier(x1234 >> 2, y1234 >> 2, x234 >> 2, y234 >> 2, x34 >> 2, y34 >> 2, x4 >> 2, y4 >> 2)

    def getboundingbox(self):
        return BezierPoint(self._minx,self._miny), BezierPoint(self._maxx,self._maxy)


    def area (self):
        m1,m2 = self.getboundingbox()
        return m2.x-m1.x, m2.y-m1.y

    def minus (self, p):
        px = p.x 
        py = p.y 
        return QuadBezier(self.p1.x - px, self.p1.y - py, 
                          self.p2.x - px, self.p2.y - py, 
                          self.p3.x - px, self.p3.y - py, 
                          self.p4.x - px, self.p4.y - py)


    def draw(self, img,pd, stackofbrushes):
        mmin,mmax = self.getboundingbox()
        numberofbrushes = len(stackofbrushes)
        largestbrushsize = stackofbrushes[numberofbrushes-1].getSize()
        print 'largestbrushsize = ', largestbrushsize
        xstart,xend = int(math.floor(mmin.x/BezierPoint.SCALEFACTOR-largestbrushsize)), int(math.ceil(mmax.x/BezierPoint.SCALEFACTOR+largestbrushsize))
        ystart,yend = int(math.floor(mmin.y/BezierPoint.SCALEFACTOR-largestbrushsize)), int(math.ceil(mmax.y/BezierPoint.SCALEFACTOR+largestbrushsize))
        print (xend - xstart) * 4, (yend - ystart) * 4, ' total area = ', ((xend - xstart) * 4) * ((yend - ystart) * 4)
        # for each pixel in the image
        for x in xrange(xstart, xend):
            for y in xrange(ystart, yend):
                pixel = BezierPoint(x*BezierPoint.SCALEFACTOR+2,y*BezierPoint.SCALEFACTOR+2) # todo: fix me
                covered, height = self.antialisedDilate(stackofbrushes, pixel, numberofbrushes)
                if covered == QuadBezier.COVERED:
                    img.MoveTo(pd,x,y)
                    #print height
                    img.Set(41*height,41*height,41*height)

    def antialisedDilate(self, stackofbrushes, p, numberofbrushes):
        mstroke = self.minus(p)  # centre the stroke
        h = 0
        n = numberofbrushes - 1
        for i in range(n,-1,-1):
            if mstroke.stroke(stackofbrushes[i]) == QuadBezier.COVERED:
                h = i
            else:
                if h == 0:
                    return QuadBezier.NOT_COVERED, 0
                return QuadBezier.COVERED, h
        return QuadBezier.COVERED, h

    def baseCase(self):
        """ returns true if the curve is primitive, that is that the length of the curve is <= 1 of the discrete space selected 
        """
        p1,p2 = self.getboundingbox()
        mx,my = p2.x-p1.x, p2.y-p1.y
        #print mx,my
        distance = 2
        if mx >= -distance and mx <= distance:
            if my > -distance and my <= distance:
                return True
        return False

    def stroke(self, b):
        """ http://pdf.aminer.org/000/593/297/antialiasing_of_curves_by_discrete_pre_filtering.pdf
        """
        # NotInDilatedBBox
        if not b.insidebox(self.getboundingbox()):
            return QuadBezier.NOT_COVERED
        if self.baseCase():
            return QuadBezier.NOT_COVERED
        if b.at(self.p1):
            return QuadBezier.COVERED
        if b.at(self.p4):
            return QuadBezier.COVERED

        left = self.subdivide(True)
        if (left.stroke(b)==QuadBezier.COVERED):
            return QuadBezier.COVERED
        right = self.subdivide(False)
        if (right.stroke(b)==QuadBezier.COVERED):
            return QuadBezier.COVERED

        return QuadBezier.NOT_COVERED


pd = None
pixels = None
def timer ():
    stackofbrushes = [Brush(6.0), Brush(7.0), Brush(9.0), Brush(11.0), Brush(13.0), Brush(15.0)] # largest last

    for i in xrange(6):
        yplus = i * 20
        bezier = QuadBezier.newRealPoint(40.0,50.0+yplus, 80.0,46.0+yplus, 120.0,46.0+yplus, 160.0,50.0+yplus)
        bezier.draw(pixels, pd, stackofbrushes)


class MyToolBar(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size(700, 700))
        self.Centre()

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, self.OnExit, id=4)
        bmp = wx.EmptyBitmap(700,700)
        # we're using the undocumented native pixel data because the memorydx object introduces artifacts on MacOS
        global pd
        global pixels

        pd = wx.NativePixelData(bmp, wx.Point(0,0), wx.Size(700,700))
        width,height = pd.GetWidth(), pd.GetHeight()
        pixels = pd.GetPixels()
        for x in xrange(width):
            for y in xrange(height):
                pixels.MoveTo(pd,x,y)
                pixels.Set(255,255,255)

        cProfile.run('timer()')

        wx.StaticBitmap(self, wx.ID_ANY, bmp)

    def OnExit(self, event):
        self.Close()

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MyToolBar(None, -1, 'Antialiasing of Curves by Discrete Pre-filtering')
        frame.Show(True)
        return True

app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```